# Decoding IPFIX packets using BitArray C#

Tags: c#, udp, decode, packets

Following on from [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666413/ipfix-data-over-udp-to-c-can-i-decode-the-data), I seem to be closer to decoding IPFIX data from a Sonicwall firewall using a UDP listener and a BitArray in C#.

I now get data in my BitArray but it doesnt make sense - I thought I would see binary in my array but I am getting values very different e.g. 8 - 10 characters some positive and some negative and the Count of the array always varies.

Here is the main part of the code I am using to get the bits:

```
byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref _myEndPoint);

BitArray bitarray = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Does any one know of any way I can decode my IPFIX data or have any pointers that will help me?

Thanks in advance,

James

---

Output from code supplied by Chris:

> byte[] bytes = {0x00, 0x0A, 0x04, 0xB4, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x6D, 0x8F, 0xC7, 0x16, 0x2B, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0xA4, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xD2, 0x8D, 0xCC, 0xC8, 0x20, 0x00, 0x26, 0x99, 0xD4, 0x5F, 0xD7, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x51, 0x90, 0xF3, 0x45, 0x4A, 0x7D, 0xE6, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x69, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0xB3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xC7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x72, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xD2, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x31, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x8F, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xEE, 0x8E, 0x42, 0xF9, 0xA0, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x00, 0x50, 0x56, 0x96, 0x00, 0x00, 0x51, 0x8D, 0x42, 0xFE, 0x51, 0x90, 0xF3, 0x46, 0x51, 0x90, 0xF3, 0x41, 0x51, 0x90, 0xF3, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC5, 0x85, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x29, 0x00, 0x00, 0xDF, 0xE1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6E, 0x65, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xEE, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x31, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x93, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF3, 0x8E, 0x5B, 0x17, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x55, 0xC0, 0xA8, 0x6F, 0x37, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0xF8, 0x23, 0x8C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF3, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x2E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xBE, 0x8E, 0xA0, 0x53, 0xA0, 0x1C, 0xC1, 0xDE, 0xA7, 0x2D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5A, 0x4A, 0xC9, 0x75, 0xF7, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x8F, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xBE, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB6, 0x8D, 0xCE, 0x0A, 0x20, 0x1C, 0xC1, 0xDE, 0xA7, 0x2D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5A, 0x5D, 0xB8, 0xDD, 0x85, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x77, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xBE, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB6, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB6, 0x8E, 0x58, 0xD0, 0xE0, 0x1C, 0xC1, 0xDE, 0xA7, 0x2D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5A, 0x58, 0xDD, 0x5E, 0xE8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x72, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x77, 0x77, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB6, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB5, 0x8E, 0x95, 0xA4, 0x60, 0x1C, 0xC1, 0xDE, 0xA7, 0x2D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5A, 0x40, 0x98, 0xD0, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x6E, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x88, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB5, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x84, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB4, 0x8E, 0xDA, 0xAB, 0xE0, 0x1C, 0xC1, 0xDE, 0xA7, 0x2D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x37, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x01, 0x5A, 0xD1, 0x55, 0x8F, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x5F, 0x00, 0x50, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x54, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xB4, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x8F, 0xF4, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};

Answer (score 4):

Can you give us a dump of one of the byte packets that you're receiving? Pass the array to the code below and it will dump it to the output window. This will help us see a raw packet.

```
    private static string PrintByteArray(byte[] bytes){
        return "byte[] bytes = {0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", ", 0x") + "};";
    }
```

Do you understand what @Paul Sasik was talking about in his answer for parsing the data? The structure is in the [RFC spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5101#section-3) that he linked to. The first two bytes (16 bits) of the packet will be the version number. I haven't read through the spec but bytes can be written in two different ways, [little and big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). So according to the spec the first two bytes should be something like `0x00 0x0a` or `0x0a 0x00`.

**EDIT**

Don't think in terms of bits versus bytes, just that the latter is a collection of 8 of the former.

The spec says that the first 16 bits (2 bytes) are the version number `0x000a` which matches what you have. It then says the next 2 bytes are the length of the entire message in bytes (it actually says octets, same thing). Your data has `0x04b4` which is `1204` in decimal which is exactly how long the byte array is. The next field is a 4 byte field for export time in seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 (aka Unix/Posix time). You have `0x4dae8ff4` which is `1,303,285,748` in decimal which according to [this site](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) is `Wed, 20 Apr 2011 07:49:08 GMT`. You can use the code below to parse the message header. Hopefully this will get you going on parsing the raw data.

```
    private static IPFIX ParseMessageHeader(byte[] bytes)
    {
        IPFIX ret = new IPFIX();
        ret.Version = ToUInt16BigEndian(bytes, 0);
        ret.Length = ToUInt16BigEndian(bytes, 2);
        ret.ExportTime = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(ToUInt32BigEndian(bytes, 4));
        ret.SequenceNumber = ToUInt32BigEndian(bytes, 8);
        ret.ObservationDomainID = ToUInt32BigEndian(bytes, 12);
        ret.Sets = new List<Set>();
        Int32 CurOctet = 16;
        Set S;
        while (true)
        {
            S = new Set();
            S.SetId = ToUInt16BigEndian(bytes, CurOctet);
            S.Length = ToUInt16BigEndian(bytes, CurOctet + 2);
            S.data = bytes.Skip(CurOctet).Take(S.Length).ToArray();
            ret.Sets.Add(S);
            CurOctet += S.Length;
            if (CurOctet >= ret.Length)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return ret;
    }

    //These two functions are from here http://snipplr.com/view/15179/adapt-systembitconverter-to-handle-big-endian-network-byte-ordering-in-order-to-create-number-types-from-bytes-and-viceversa/
    //BitConverter.ToUInt16 would parse the results in "little endian" order so 0x000a would actually be parsed as 0x0a00 and give you 2,560 instead of 10.
    //The spec says that everything should be in "big endian" (also known as "network order"
    public static UInt16 ToUInt16BigEndian(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        return System.BitConverter.ToUInt16(value.Reverse().ToArray(), value.Length - sizeof(UInt16) - startIndex);
    }
    public static UInt32 ToUInt32BigEndian(byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        return System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(value.Reverse().ToArray(), value.Length - sizeof(UInt32) - startIndex);
    }
    struct IPFIX
    {
        public UInt16 Version;
        public UInt16 Length;
        public DateTime ExportTime;
        public UInt32 SequenceNumber;
        public UInt32 ObservationDomainID;
        public List<Set> Sets;
    }
    struct Set
    {
        public UInt16 SetId;
        public UInt16 Length;
        public byte[] data;
        public SetType SetType
        {
            get
            {
                if (SetId == 2) return SetType.TemplateSet;
                if (SetId == 3) return SetType.OptionTemplate;
                if (SetId > 255) return SetType.DataSet;
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("SetId", "SetId not in expected range of 2, 3 or >255");
            }
        }

    }
    enum SetType { TemplateSet, OptionTemplate, DataSet };
```

One thing to be careful of is "endian-ness". Windows parses values as little endian by default but all values here need to be parsed as big endian per spec. The normal BitConvertor class won't work here so there are two helper functions above that tweak it to work as needed. Also, you'll see that instead of regular `int`s I'm using `UInt16` and `UInt32`. That's also per spec. An `Int16` holds both negative and positive numbers while an `UInt16` doesn't have the concept of either (although we generally think of it as positive).

Comment: Hi Chris - I have an understanding of what Paul Sasik was saying.  I wanted to get some eligable data to cross reference with the RFC spec to help me get a full understanding first.  I have outputted your code but its quite big so please see my edits in my original question.

Comment: So do I need to be working with bytes rather than bits? Sorry to be asking questions that might be obvious to you but this is new ground for me.

Comment: @Jimbo James, I added an explanation of how to parse the data along with some code. Hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: @Jimbo James, I took the code a little further and parsed out the payload. After the header the message can contain several templates or data sets. The message that you posted consisted entirely of a data set payload (ID=257, Length=1188). Unfortunately, in order to read this you'd need a message with a Template Set whose ID is 257 and we don't have that here. So basically in order to read this message you need to get instructions from another message. It might not be convenient to post more bytes here but feel free to email me if you want me to try to parse them.

Comment: Hi Chris - really really appreciate your help with this - thank you!  I'll let you know how it goes as soon as I get chance to integrate this code.  Nice to feel like I'm making progress with this, with a little help ;-)

Comment: @Jimbo James, where you able to get this to work? I'm desperately looking for IPFIX C# decoding code...